# String Input for user prompts

Tags: java

I am trying to write a program that allows the user to input two values. The first value is the radius of a circle. The second value is which calculation they would like to perform, D for Diameter, C for Circumference, or A for Area. The program would then calculate what the user wanted and display it on the screen.

This is what I have written so far, unfortunately my input for the characters are incorrectly lined.

What changes do I have to make to this code so that I can get it to do what I want?

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter Radius: ");
        System.out.println("Enter D for Diameter, C for Circumference, or A for Area");
        double radius = sc.nextDouble();
        String input=null;
        {
            if (input.equals("A")) {
                //Area = PIradiusradius
                double Area = Math.PI * (radius * radius);
                System.out.println("The area of the cirlce is: ");
            } else if (input.equals("C")) {
                //Circumference = 2*PI*radius 
                double Circumference = Math.PI * 2 * radius;
                System.out.println("The circumference of the circle is: ");
            } else if (input.equals("D")) {
                //Diameter = 2 * radius 
                double Diameter = 2 * radius;
                System.out.println("The diameter of the circle is: ");
            }
            sc.close();
        }
```

Comment: Java and JavaScript are different programming languages.

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues with your code.I have modified your code based on my understanding.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter Radius: ");
        double radius = sc.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter D for Diameter, C for Circumference, or A for Area");
        String input = sc.next();
        {
            if (input.equals("A")) {
                //Area = PIradiusradius
                double Area = Math.PI * (radius * radius);
                System.out.println("The area of the cirlce is: "+Area);
            } else if (input.equals("C")) {
                //Circumference = 2*PI*radius
                double Circumference = Math.PI * 2 * radius;
                System.out.println("The circumference of the circle is: "+Circumference);
            } else if (input.equals("D")) {
                //Diameter = 2 * radius
                double Diameter = 2 * radius;
                System.out.println("The diameter of the circle is: "+Diameter);
            }
            sc.close();
        }
```

It first ask for `radius` and then for `A` `D` or `C` and based on that calculate the things.